# How to automatically display Lightbox when loading the page

Tags: primefaces, lightbox

What I want is to display a lightbox right after the page is loaded. I mean, when the user receives the page, the lightbox automatically shows and stays on untill it is closed. How can I do this?

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
  xmlns:ui="http://java.sun.com/jsf/facelets"
  xmlns:h="http://java.sun.com/jsf/html"
  xmlns:f="http://java.sun.com/jsf/core"
  xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui">

<ui:composition template="/WEB-INF/include/template.xhtml">
    <ui:define name="title">
        <h:outputText value="#{jorBundle.AppName}"></h:outputText>
    </ui:define>
    <ui:define name="body">

        <p:lightBox width="20%" height="80%" >  
            <h:outputLink value="#" title="Marcel Vieira" >  
                <h:outputText value="some description here"/>  
            </h:outputLink>  

            <f:facet name="inline">  
                <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                    <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ich.jpg" />  
                    <h:outputText style="color:#FFFFFF" value="some text in here...." />                                                                             
                </h:panelGrid>
            </f:facet>  
        </p:lightBox> 

        <p:panel header="#{jorBundle.Welcome}">
            <p><h:outputText value="#{jorBundle.WelcomeMessage}"></h:outputText></p>
        </p:panel>

        <p:panel header="Gráfico Divisões UPB" menuTitle="menu" collapsed="true" >
            <p><h:outputText value="Gráfico"></h:outputText></p>

        </p:panel>
    </ui:define>
</ui:composition>
</html>
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could use the primefaces javascript, which requires an ID on the lightbox.

Component:

```
<p:lightBox width="20%" height="80%" id='myLightBox'>  
    <h:outputLink value="#" title="Marcel Vieira" >  
        <h:outputText value="some description here"/>  
    </h:outputLink>  

    <f:facet name="inline">  
        <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
            <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ich.jpg" />  
            <h:outputText style="color:#FFFFFF" value="some text in here...." />                                                                             
        </h:panelGrid>
    </f:facet>  
</p:lightBox>
```

Javascript:

```
<script>
    document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
       PF('myLightBox').show();
    });
</script>
```

Comment: dehrg, thanks for your Javascript solution. But it was easy as we thought (see my answer below).

Answer (score 0):

A simple solution is to set the visible attribute to true:

```
<p:lightBox width="20%" height="80%" visible="true">  
        <h:outputLink value="#" title="Marcel Vieira" >  
            <h:outputText value="some description here"/>  
        </h:outputLink>  

        <f:facet name="inline">  
            <h:panelGrid columns="2">  
                <p:graphicImage value="/resources/images/ich.jpg" />  
                <h:outputText style="color:#FFFFFF" value="some text in here...." />                                                                             
            </h:panelGrid>
        </f:facet>  
    </p:lightBox>
```